# What does this button on my Electrolux refrigerator do?

Tags: refrigerator

On my Electrolux refrigerator (model: ER8029B), what does this button do?

[image: An unknown button]

Comment: Defrost, possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is a climate control switch. The button should be used if the ambient temperature is below 16°C.

Reference: electrolux-ui.com (model: ER8029B)

(The climate control switch can also be used if you are freezing a lot of stuff at once. You should then activate it 12 hours in advance.)